# How to secure WMS/WFS request from Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, proxy

Currently anyone can go to inspect-> network and get my rest url and access my data from geoserver, I want to secure my connection (probably by adding proxy server) so that only authenticated persons can get data when they run the url.
I have approximately 10000 users.

Comment: There's no such thing as a REST URL

Answer (score 1):

Knowing your rest-url will not gain them anything unless they also know your administrator password (which is not still `geoserver` is it?).

You can use the built in [REST Security that GeoServer provides](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/rest.html) to allow different users different levels of access.

Comment: but still when we paste that url in chrome, we can get the json data back. How can we stop that ?

Comment: which URL do you mean?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/company/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=company%3Adistrict&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson 

like this, What if I don't want to anyone to copy this url from network and  use this url to get data . how can I do that ?

Comment: Ok, two things 1) that is not a REST url and 2) this how GeoServer and WFS work. If you don't need or want a WFS then turn the service off (global settings),

Comment: I want to create system in such a way that I can fetch the WFS data from my program but if anyone copies and paste that url , it will not work. 

Any guidance in that way will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: then you need to enable security - https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/index.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107716/discussion-between-krishna-lodha-and-ian-turton).